# hector_turtlebot rosmake failed

Tags: turtlebot, ros-fuerte, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

I was trying to install the hector_turtlebot package from [hector_turtlebot wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_turtlebot?distro=fuerte). I am using ros fuerte on ubuntu 12.04.

I used the following commands to download the package and rosmake-

```
$ cd ~/ros_workspace
$ svn co  https://tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/hector_turtlebot
$ rosmake hector_turtlebot
```

---

When running the rosmake hector_turtlebot the build failed. The rosmake output files are attached here [rosmake_output](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qpf3pb36h02upn7/rosmake_output-20130909-205636.zip)

```
turtlebot@turtlebot:~/ros_workspace$ rosmake hector_turtlebot
```

[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['hector_turtlebot']
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/turtlebot/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130909-205636
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['hector_turtlebot'] to:
['hector_turtlebot_apps', 'hector_turtlebot_description', 'hector_turtlebot_gazebo', 'hector_turtlebot_scan_filter']
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> colladadom [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> urdf_interface [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslang  No Makefile in package roslang
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< urdf_interface ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf_interface
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< colladadom ROS_NOBUILD in package colladadom
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> hector_turtlebot_description [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rostest  No Makefile in package rostest
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosbuild  No Makefile in package rosbuild
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> xacro [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp  No Makefile in package roscpp
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> urdf_parser [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< xacro ROS_NOBUILD in package xacro
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> collada_parser [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< urdf_parser ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf_parser
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< geometry_msgs  No Makefile in package geometry_msgs
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> mk [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< mk  No Makefile in package mk
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< sensor_msgs  No Makefile in package sensor_msgs
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< collada_parser ROS_NOBUILD in package collada_parser
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> urdf [ make ]
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> hector_turtlebot_scan_filter [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> turtlebot_gazebo [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< urdf ROS_NOBUILD in package urdf
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> turtlebot_description [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< turtlebot_gazebo ROS_NOBUILD in package turtlebot_gazebo
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> common_rosdeps [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< turtlebot_description ROS_NOBUILD in package turtlebot_description
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_msgs  No Makefile in package std_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> trajectory_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< trajectory_msgs  No Makefile in package trajectory_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> gazebo_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< gazebo_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package gazebo_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roslib  No Makefile in package roslib
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> bullet [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< bullet ROS_NOBUILD in package bullet
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< common_rosdeps ROS_NOBUILD in package common_rosdeps
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> ogre [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< ogre ROS_NOBUILD in package ogre
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> std_srvs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< std_srvs  No Makefile in package std_srvs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosconsole  No Makefile in package rosconsole
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> angles [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> roswtf [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rospy  No Makefile in package rospy
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< roswtf  No Makefile in package roswtf
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs  No Makefile in package rosgraph_msgs
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosservice  No Makefile in package rosservice
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure ROS_NOBUILD in package dynamic_reconfigure
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> protobuf [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< protobuf ROS_NOBUILD in package protobuf
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< message_filters  No Makefile in package message_filters
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> tf [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> nav_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> gazebo [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< nav_msgs  No Makefile in package nav_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> turtlebot_driver [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< turtlebot_driver ROS_NOBUILD in package turtlebot_driver
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> diagnostic_msgs [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< diagnostic_msgs  No Makefile in package diagnostic_msgs
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> orocos_kdl [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< orocos_kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package orocos_kdl
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> python_orocos_kdl [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< python_orocos_kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package python_orocos_kdl
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> kdl [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package kdl
No Makefile in package kdl
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> turtlebot_node [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< turtlebot_node ROS_NOBUILD in package turtlebot_node
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> bond [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< bond ROS_NOBUILD in package bond
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> smclib [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< smclib ROS_NOBUILD in package smclib
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> bondcpp [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< bondcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package bondcpp
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> nodelet [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbag  No Makefile in package rosbag
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> nodelet_topic_tools [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< nodelet_topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet_topic_tools
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pcl_ros [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pcl_ros ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl_ros
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pointcloud_to_laserscan [ make ]
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pointcloud_to_laserscan ROS_NOBUILD in package pointcloud_to_laserscan
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> hector_turtlebot_apps [ make ]
[ rosmake ] All 21 linesector_turtlebot_descripti... [ 4 Active 49/55 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
[rosbuild] Building package hector_turtlebot_description
Failed to invoke /opt/ros/fuerte/bin/rospack deps-manifests hector_turtlebot_description
[rospack] Error: package/stack hector_turtlebot_description depends on non-existent package hector_sensors_description

CMake Error at /opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129 (message):

```
Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package
'hector_turtlebot_description'.  Look above for errors from rospack itself.
Aborting.  Please fix the broken dependency!
```

Call Stack (most recent call first):
/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)

### -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package hector_turtlebot_description written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/turtlebot/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130909-205636/hector_turtlebot_description/build_output.log
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< hector_turtlebot_description [FAIL] [ 0.19 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package hector_turtlebot_description.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< gazebo ROS_NOBUILD in package gazebo
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< hector_turtlebot_apps [PASS] [ 0.37 seconds ]
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< hector_turtlebot_scan_filter [PASS] [ 0.45 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 53 packages with 1 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/turtlebot/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130909-205636

---

**Could someone please help me why the build failed and any solution to this problem. Also did anyone has successfully implemented the hector_turtlebot on their turtlebot 1 with hokuyo lidar? Please help.  Thanks..**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/77536/hector_turtlebot-rosmake-failed/) by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 340 on 2013-09-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems you also need this package : http://wiki.ros.org/hector_sensors_description

because you can read :

```
 [rospack] Error: package/stack hector_turtlebot_description depends on non-existent package hector_sensors_description
```

---

Originally posted by [Jbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/1000/jbot/) with karma: 429 on 2013-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on 2013-09-09**:
thank you, no errors now.